# Get IResources methods in eclipse development?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and need to list of IMethods that belong to an IResource.

I see IType has a getMethods function but not sure how to go about converting an IResource to an IType

Help appreciated

Nicky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step, get the `ICompilationUnit` from the `IResource`:

```
 ICompilationUnit icu = (ICompilationUnit) JavaCore.create(resource);
```

Next, use either `getTypes()` or `getType(String)` to get your `IType`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full solution, but some ideas:

- globally an IResource cannot be converted/cast to IType (AFAIK)
- as IType is specific to the JDT, I suggest opening a Java resource file, converting it to ICompilationUnit, that can be traversed to get the IType

For the basic idea I suggest looking at the [tutorial page of Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html), more specifically Section 4, where it creates a menu item to the Project Navigator, that converts a Java file to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

IResource represents a file (or folder, or project) in the workspace. They can be C++, javascript or even image files. As the other repliers said, the IResource itself isn't the Java file; you need the ICompilationUnit.